# Alternative way to phrase the relative clause "which I don't find X to be"

Tags: clauses, relative-clauses

I wrote down the following sentence. But I think it's quite awkward. Besides, [Google tells me](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=%22which%20I%20don%27t%20find%20him%20to%20be%22) that the clause *which I don't find him to be* occurs only twice across the internet.

> He'll do this if he's smart, which I don't find him to be.

I was trying to combine two thoughts into a single sentence.

> I don't find him to be smart
>
> He'll do this if he's smart.

Is there an alternate way to articulate the thoughts in a single sentence that's more elegant?

Comment: "He'll do this if he's smart...which he's not!" - this sounds normal to me.

Comment: Your sentences seem contradictory. Since he's not smart, he won't do it. Unless you are not sure.

Comment: ... Which means it's not sensible to combine them in a regular way. Kristina's abrupt contrast works, as a slick comment.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that my comment was terse and "slick" as Edwin said, but not nice nor polite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original sentence doesn't sound awkward or clumsy to me. The relative clause “which I don't find/consider him (to be)” is perfectly normal and common.

It is somewhat formal in register, but that's not because of the relative clause-ness of it—the construction *find/consider X to be Y* is just a bit above normal, colloquial speech in register. The more register-neutral construction would be *think that X is Y*.

A more natural phrasing (by which I mean a phrasing that fits the colloquialness of the subject matter by being very natural in everyday, informal speech) would thus be:

> He’ll do this if he’s smart… which I don't think he is.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain their downvote? I’ll be happy to improve upon the answer if I can.

Answer (score 3):

''If he had any sense, he would do this.''

Leave your opinion of the subjects smartness implied. It works even better in the past tense; ''If he had any sense, he would have done this.''

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you mean is

> If he were smart, he would do this, but I fear he is not.

or

> If he were smart, which I fear he is not, he would do this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you want to use *find* instead of *think* or *believe*.

If you're stressing your finding, you shouldn't put it in a non-restrictive relative clause.
Relative clauses of any kind are for backgrounded presupposed material, not important matters.

*Think* or *believe* -- besides meaning the same thing -- have the advantage that they can both take
tensed complement clauses, with or without *that* -- in this case, "without *that*" is what we want.

Complement clauses are just regular sentences, just like the tensed clause *if he's smart*.
Conjunction reduction always works better with a parallel construction

Viz (as @Janus has pointed out - referential indices and zero trace supplied below)

- *He'll do this if he's smartᵢ, whichᵢ I don't think/believe he is `∅`ᵢ.*

Comment: I don't get the non-restrictive comment. *Smart* seems to be self  contained, it's not like it's a special kind of smart: *He seems to be smart which is bright, not smart which is sarcastic* or the like - if you see what I mean. Your last example seems to be a non-restrictive clause too...

Comment: The OQ had a non-restrictive relative clause ", which I don't find him to be". I modified it to a different non-restrictive relative clause. I don't believe that's what Huddleston and Pullum call them, but I forget what they use. Most of their terminological innovations have gone unremarked and unused in the literature. If you mean the second sentence, you shouldn't put it in a relative clause at all, of any sort, if you want to stress it. But certainly this applies to non-restrictive relatives.

Comment: Hmm, imo *I've just seen the police, who say they've arrested your wife.* It seems to me that however much you want to stress the relative clause there it can't be restrictive (assuming you don't want to differentiate a specific proportion of the police who've said that they've arrested your wife!).

Comment: That's effectively the same as _and they say_, but not as prominent; it pretends to be about the police, while hiding the bad news in a subordinate clause instead of appending another assertion.

Comment: Yeah, I don't disagree!

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that _think_ and _believe_ have the advantage that they can take tensed complement clauses with or without _that_ in (seeming) opposition to _find_. In my English, at least, _find_ does that just fine, too: “I find (that) I enjoy books much more the second time I read them”, for example.